# Query to join two tables in order to get the 'names' based on the 'ids'

Tags: mysql

I have two tables **base_list** and **entries_table**

The base_list has the names of all the dishes in it, their IDs, and their names -- this is the master list.

The entries_table is a table with 10 columns. The columns correspond to the ranking people put them in when they vote. So for example, John Doe will select 10 dishes, and then the id's of those dishes are saved in the entries_table. Whenever anyone casts their vote of 10 dishes, it is saved on this table.

I want to create a query where I'd end up with the entries_table, but instead of the ID's, I'd end up with the names of the dishes.

So far I've tried inner joining, but I haven't found success. I'm not really sure on how to go about this.

Comment: I think that you are struggling because the way that you have structured entries_table means that you would have to make 10 joins to the base_list - one per column of ID  - in order to get the data out how you would want it. There is a 'more relational way' to design the database and achieve this, but it depends on what outcome you are looking for beyond the initial question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your table design makes this complicated. Your entries_table should looke like this:

`user_ID, dish_ID, ranking, date, selection_ID`

(something like selection_ID will be needed if someone makes more than one selection per date)

With your current design you could use an if clause that includes all dishes. But depending on the number of dishes that is probably too much work.

However this should work for you:

```
Select b.dish_name as dish_1,
       c.dish_name as dish_2,
       d.dish_name as dish_3,
       e.dish_name as dish_4,
       f.dish_name as dish_5,
       g.dish_name as dish_6,
       h.dish_name as dish_7,
       i.dish_name as dish_8,
       j.dish_name as dish_9,
       k.dish_name as dish_10,
from entries_table a
left join base_list as b on(a.dish_id_1 = b.dish_id)
left join base_list as c on(a.dish_id_2 = c.dish_id)
left join base_list as d on(a.dish_id_3 = d.dish_id)
left join base_list as e on(a.dish_id_4 = e.dish_id)
left join base_list as f on(a.dish_id_5 = f.dish_id)
left join base_list as g on(a.dish_id_6 = g.dish_id)
left join base_list as h on(a.dish_id_7 = h.dish_id)
left join base_list as i on(a.dish_id_8 = i.dish_id)
left join base_list as j on(a.dish_id_9 = j.dish_id)
left join base_list as k on(a.dish_id_10 = k.dish_id)
```

I don't know your exact column names. Just replace my column names with yours and add more columns if needed and it should give you the result you are looking for.